# What's wrong with a question about the rarest Steam achievements?

Tags: discussion, closing, specific-question

I asked [this question about the rarest Steam achievements](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/166213/8798), and it got put on hold for being too broad almost immediately.

While I disagreed with "too broad", I realized the question might be "too localized" as the answers would change over time. So I rewrote the question to not ask for any specific achievements--instead focusing on a method to find a list of currently rarest achievements. After editing I flagged the post for moderators and fully expected the question to be reopened by now.

Is there something else wrong with this question? I feel it's a very good fit for the QA format, but I do realize it might be off-topic here. I'm not that familiar with how you do things here. Should I still edit the question somehow?

Comment: I was also surprised by the amount of downvotes I received after the question was put on hold (I can't see the up/down ratio, but I think there were two upvotes at one point). While this is very subjective, I wonder if there are people who *want* to downvote and see putting on hold as a permission to do that.

Comment: I declined your flag; your question was already accumulating reopen votes, and mod intervention is *not* needed to accelerate that process. We are as reluctant to reopen unilaterally as we are to close. Be thankful for that.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I do agree that is for the best. I just didn't think about it that way. Thanks for letting the community do its thing!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/124106/237685. Really, especially even more so if it's flagged - reopen it/close it if it's obvious, do nothing if you're not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My understanding of the system is that if you edit a question that was 'on hold' it is automatically nominated for reopening, and is put into the [reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions). At this point it takes 5 users with 3000+ rep to agree that the edit(s) fixed whatever issues caused it to be put on hold in the first place (Just as it took 5 users to put it on hold).

Unless there was some clear evidence of shenanigans going on that caused it to be closed improperly, or there was a discussion here on meta relating to the closure (and there was a clear consensus that it should be reopened); getting one's question reopened should generally be left to the community, rather than getting a single mod to overturn a closure.

The above being said, your question (as I have been typing this answer) was sitting at 4/5 reopen votes. After looking over the original question and the edit, I agree that the scope has been fixed, and have cast the 5th vote, the question is now open.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I'm just hoping someone can answer the question... :)